# opening a SherlockFragment activity from non activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to open a SherlockFragment activity from non activity class 
using this from an normal activity

Android.app.Activity >> NonActivityClass >> SherlockFragmentActivity

Passing this from Activity class to NonActivityClass and trying to start the SherlockFragmentActivity

Code -

```
private void changeFragment(Activity act) {

        Fragment profileFrag = new New_ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((SherlockFragmentActivity) act)
                .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        try {
            ((SherlockFragmentActivity) act).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .popBackStackImmediate(profileFrag.toString(),
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {

        }

        transaction.addToBackStack(profileFrag.toString());
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFrag);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        ((SherlockFragmentActivity) act).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .executePendingTransactions();

    }
```

**I am getting error in**

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((SherlockFragmentActivity) act)
                .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

**Exception** - java.lang.ClassCastException: activity cannot be cast to com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. You are aware of the fact that ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated for 2 years?

b.

> activity cannot be cast to
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity

pretty much says it all. You can't cast an `android.app.Activity` to a `SherlockFragmentActivity` because from [what I can see](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java) `SherlockFragmentActivity` doesn't extend `android.app.Activity` .

c. You either have to do

```
activity.getFragmentManager()
```

or, if you must use `SupportFragmentManager`, you first activity has to be a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` so you can do

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Either way, get rid of `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: Hi can you share me a code to open SherlockFragment 1 from SherlockFragment 2 i have tried using normal intent but it doesn't work,